# Why are these functions abstract , where to find the body(specific implementation) of them？

Tags: java, android, android-source

[image: Screenshot]

I want to know the implementation of the function `getPackageInfo` (because I wanna know where is the package stored they are referring to), so I went to [this](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/content/pm/PackageManager.java) to see the source code, but only found an abstract method there.

```
public abstract PackageInfo getPackageInfo(String packageName, int flags) throws NameNotFoundException;
```

Where is the implementation of the method?

Comment: You should be able to highlight `getPackageInfo` and right-click, and there should be something that lets you Goto -> Source

Comment: @liquidsystem - no, not really, as the source of the implementation is part of Android itself, rather than part of the SDK, and so would not normally be visible to an IDE.

Answer (score 2):

the implementation of getPackageInfo method is in com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService

```
 @Override
public PackageInfo getPackageInfo(String packageName, int flags, int userId) {
    // reader
    synchronized (mPackages) {
        PackageParser.Package p = mPackages.get(packageName);
        if (DEBUG_PACKAGE_INFO)
            Log.v(TAG, "getPackageInfo " + packageName + ": " + p);
        if (p != null) {
            return generatePackageInfo(p, flags);
        }
        if((flags & PackageManager.GET_UNINSTALLED_PACKAGES) != 0) {
            return generatePackageInfoFromSettingsLPw(packageName, flags, userId);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

you can look [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/483f3b06ea84440a082e21b68ec2c2e54046f5a6/services/java/com/android/server/pm/PackageManagerService.java)